# Java: using Collection.sort and lambda expression in combination with the ternary operator leads to unexpected result

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
import java.util.*;

class ClassA {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        var list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("test");
        list.add("abc");

        Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a.length() >= b.length() ? 1 : 0); // [test, abc]
        //Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));                 // [abc, test]

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

I thought `Collection.sort()` would sort accending. I thought `a.length()` is 4 and `b.length()` is 3 which would evaluate as `(4 >= 3)` true. So `a.length() >= b.length() ? 1 : 0` would return 1 and mean that `"test"` is greater than `"abc"`. So it should be sorted like `[abc, test]`.

But I only get the result `[abc, test]` when I change the code to `a.length() >= b.length() ? 1 : -1`, which seems to indicate that `a.length() >= b.length()`evaluates as `false`. Why is that?

Why does the first lambda expression lead to `[test, abc]`, while the modified version leads to `[abc, test]`?

`Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));` works like expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the doc of `Comparator`: [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), or the lambda you're using to implement it, must return a negative value if `a < b`, not just a positive value if `a > b`.  It must also return zero if `a` is equal to (or compares equal to) `b`.  This differs from the expectation in some other programming languages, which is, I assume, what confused you.

It would be an entirely valid implementation of `sort` to *never* pay attention to positive outputs, only negative outputs.  It would appear that it didn't do the comparison in the order you expected.

You can implement this comparator correctly as `(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length())`, or much more simply as `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)`.

Comment: Also IIRC needs to return 0 if equal, so returning 1 for same length is also not a good idea.

Comment: I understand that a < b should be negative, a == b should be 0 and a > b should be positive, which is what a.compareTo(b) does.
What I don't get is why changing the ternary operator false case will change the result of the sorting. I still don't get how it works. To clarify: I'm more interested in why this works the way it does then in finding a way to get the correct result.

Comment: @richard Regarding your comment "a == b"… No, double-equals-sign means identical object reference, that both `a` & `b` point to the same object, to the very same place in memory. The discussion here is not about object identity. The discussion here is about the [`Comparator#compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) method. This method usually considers *content* of the object's state rather than object identity. Two different objects in memory may be considered equal in the mind of a comparator.

Comment: Yeah right, my mistake. I meant a.equals(b). So the problem is that (a, b) does not mean it will result in "test" >= "abc", but in this case it will compare "abc" >= "test" and give me 0 for it, which results in the list not being sorted in the expected order. I think I understand now.